# How to edit code on server directly in VScode

Tags: html, css, wordpress, visual-studio-code, deployment

I am writing code that will be deployed to a server. Right now I have to upload the code each time I change it. Is there any way to edit the code live on the server in Visual Studio code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are some extension in the editor who provide that function this can be done in VS Code very simple. Just **search in extensions for Keyword 'FTP'** ...

Two Examples:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukasz-wronski.ftp-sync

Both are very popular.

At the moment I personally use FTP-Simple. But have a look on your own. It depends on the things you wonna do. And don't worry ... it's a little bit tricky at the beginning to figure out how to setup and how they work ... but when you are in it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what hosting you are deploying to. You can SSH into your server with most providers and use a command line editor such as `nano` or `vim`. Keep in mind, this won't keep the version on your computer up to date and the changes will be overwritten if you redeploy. Alternatively, If you have a VPS and want to edit the files in an IDE on your local computer, maybe a file transfer system like FTP or SMB would work. I don't suggest it though, there are huge [security issues](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2018/12/how-threat-actors-are-using-smb-vulnerabilities/) with them.

For Azure web apps, I've found that the Azure plugin for VScode is a quick and easy way to deploy my app. It's not quite real time but it's very easy to redeploy after updating. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/extensions

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to connect remotely to a couple Raspberry Pis, and a home server.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh